# react native how to pass a state to all children

Tags: reactjs, react-native

```
    import {
    ImageBackground
} from 'react-native';

export const CustomContext = React.createContext(1);
export default class MainBackGround extends React.Component {
    state ={
        lang:'en'
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <CustomContext.Provider value={this.state.lang}>
                <ImageBackground>
                    { this.props.children } 
                </ImageBackground>
            </CustomContext.Provider>
        )
    }
}
```

child component

```
import MainBackground, {CustomContext} from '../components/MainBackground';
export default class MyChildComponent extends React.Component {

    render() {
        return (
                <CustomContext.Consumer>
                { value => (
                <ScrollView >               
                    <Text>{value}</Text>
                </ScrollView>
                )}
                </CustomContext.Consumer>
        );
    }
}
```

How can I pass state `a` to all the children?

I just update the code closer to my real code

problem I'm getting value as `1` instead of `en` ( the  is showing 1 instead en)

Comment: You should use `ReactContext` for this, you can read here https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html

Answer (score 2):

The [context API](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) might be what you're looking for. It's designed to share data between many, often deeply nested components. This provides an alternative to prop drilling.

This removes the need for you to drill down props, so in my example I have replaced your state field, with the creation of a react context.

Note that this does create coupling between components, thus can lead to the components being hard to reuse.

Untested example below.

```
import React from "react";

// Create a context, you'd probably place this in a /contexts
// folder, i.e. not in the component file itself.

//Note we're passing in a default value, I took 1 from your
// state field.
export const CustomContext = React.createContext(1);

export default class MainBackGround extends React.Component {

    render() {

        // All children can have access to the context variable,
        // by utilising CustomContext.Consumer. 

        // Note, you can override the default value of 1
        // and pass a 'value' prop to the CustomContext.Provider
        // below, e.g. <CustomContext.Provider value={5}>
        return (
            <CustomContext.Provider>
                { this.props.children } 
            </CustomContext.Provider>
        )
    }
}
```

Then in one of your children

```
import React from "react";
import {Text} from "react-native";

// This is the context created in the above example.
import CustomContext from "./where you saved it.";

export default class SomeChildComponent extends React.Component {

    render () {
        // '1' will be rendered in the Text element
        // as 1 was given as the default value of the context.  
        return (
            <CustomContext.Consumer>
                {value => (
                    <Text>
                        {value}
                    </Text>
                )}
            </CustomContext.Consumer>
        );
    }
}
```

Note this is of course less expensive than the previous answer, which could be especially useful if you have many children. I.e. your are not cloning every child.

The example i've given is very barebones, it utilises the default value you provide to the context API. You can change the value defined in the Context Provider.

E.g.

```
export const CustomContext = React.createContext(1);

export default class MainBackGround extends React.Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <CustomContext.Provider value={5}>
                { this.props.children } 
            </CustomContext.Provider>
        )
    }
}
```

This would then print 5 in the child component in my original example, i.e. we are not relying on the default value given when creating the new context.

In short, first example omitted the 'value' prop you *can* pass to the Context.Provider element, as this is optional, the default value will be provided in this instance.

**Alternative**

As an alternative, I would advise a state management library like [Redux](https://redux.js.org/introduction/getting-started).

Comment: how do you put the `this.state.a` into the `React.createContext(1);` the state is viable in my case

Comment: You wouldn't hook up state to the default value of the context you create, rather, if you has your value in state and what to use that, you'd utilise the value prop, passing in your value from state, e.g. <CustomContext.Provider value={state.foobar}>

Comment: The default value is only used, if the value prop is not passes to the Provider in scope, thus if you always pass in the value prop, the default value will never be used.

Comment: I dont why, but its passing 1 as value instead of the state

Answer (score 0):

There are three approaches I see for your problem:-

1) Using render prop pattern

2) Using `React.cloneElement`

3) Using React.Context API

Here is the [code sandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/focused-nightingale-7vdwn) with usage of all three methods. Use whichever suits your need.

Hope that helps!!!